# Best practices to hide comunication between component and service in an Angular library

Tags: angular, angular-library

I'm creating an Angular library that allow to show messages inside a component's template and it's composed by a 'MessagesService' that is used to set messages and a 'MessagesComponent', used to show messages inside pages where it's referenced in.

The MessagesComponent should be able to retrieve message from the MessagesService.

The MessagesComponent's parent component should not be able to access the message variable. To set the message the parent should use the serivce's provided functions.

At the moment my best idea has been to create an other service that:

- is injected in the MessagesComponent and in the MessagesService;
- handles the communication between the two;
- is not exported from library.

Is this the correct way to do that or are there better ways?

**EDIT:**

What I would like is that the MessagesComponent's parent should be able to call `showMessage()` but not be able to read `message` value. This variable should be visible only by the MessagesComponent.

My idea was to add an other service (CommunicationService) that contains the message.

When the MessagesComponent's parent call the `showMessage()`, the MessagesService set the value in the CommunicationService and the MessagesComponent receive the message using an Observable.

MessagesService

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MessagesService {
  constructor(private commService: CommunicatorService) {}

  showMessage(message: string) {
    this.commService.setMessage(message);
  }
}
```

CommunicationServices

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommunicatorService {

  private message: BehaviorSubject<string>;

  constructor() { }

  setMessage(message) {
    this.message.next(message);
  }

  getMessage() {
    return this.message.asObservable();
  }
}
```

MessagesComponent

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'lib-messages',
  template: `
    <p>
      {{ commService.getMessage() | async }}
    </p>
  `,
  styles: []
})
export class MessagesComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public commService: CommunicatorService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

This way, the parent component cannot see the message variable but the MessagesComponet can.

I would like to know if that is the correct way to implement such a thing or if there are better ways.

Comment: Please provide some code, is hard to figure your problem without it

Comment: "I would like to do so that the MessagesComponent could be able to retrieve message from the MessagesService but that his parent component could not access the message variable but only the provided functions to set the message." - really needs some code snippte :) What you've written in this one sentence would simply mean set all internal variables/functions to private and that's it?

Comment: I edited the question, hope is more clear now :)

Answer (score 0):

A private member means it can only be readed from the container class, it means if a class inherit from it, that class wont have access to that member, the member still exists, but you cant access it.

From ts docs:

> When a member is marked private, it cannot be accessed from outside of its containing classs

You cant hide the member, you can only limit the access

Also you have static properties which i think will suit your case

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#static-properties

Static properties are only visible in the class itself, not on the instances.

From ts docs:

> We can also create static members of a class, those that are visible on the class itself rather than on the instances.

Comment: I know how visibility works, I would like to know if my implementation is correct or if are there better way to do what I did

Comment: As long as it works for your case is correct, nothing more to be checked, if it suits your requirements its ok